# A good org-mode sandbox/demo document

Tags: org-mode

I'm looking for a good org-mode "sandbox" or demonstration document that contains a comprehensive survey of general-purpose org-mode features as examples in a self-descriptive form.

My intended application is as a general purpose "org scratch buffer" to test code without needing to write sample content.

For example (from `testing/examples/normal.org`):

```
#+TITLE: Example file
#+OPTIONS: num:nil ^:nil
#+STARTUP: hideblocks

This is an example file for use by the Org-mode tests.

* top
** code block
   :PROPERTIES:
   :header-args: :tangle yes
   :CUSTOM_ID: code-block-section
   :END:
Here are a couple of code blocks.

#+begin_src emacs-lisp :tangle no
  ;; 94839181-184f-4ff4-a72f-94214df6f5ba
  (message "I am code")
#+end_src
* accumulating properties in drawers
 :PROPERTIES:
 :header-args+: :var bar=2
 :header-args: :var foo=1
 :ID:       75282ba2-f77a-4309-a970-e87c149fe125
 :END:

#+begin_src emacs-lisp :results silent
 (list bar foo)
#+end_src
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are plenty of org-mode example documents.

Some interesting picks:

1. [Erik Schulte's scraps](http://eschulte.github.io/org-scraps/) is an aged collection of babel test cases.
2. [Organize Your Life In Plain Text!](http://doc.norang.ca/org-mode.html) by Bernt Hansen is a nice read.
3. [Emacs org-mode examples and cookbook](http://ehneilsen.net/notebook/orgExamples/org-examples.html) by Erik Nielsen is a nice collection of org-export features and options.

Answer (score 0):

This is my favourite: https://writequit.org/denver-emacs/presentations/files/example.org.html

The only missing thing is the header with the document title/author/...